# Java - Regular Expressions - alphanumeric plus /-

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to generate a regular expression in Java for alphanumeric and / and - character. I tried the following but it didnt work

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\/\-#]*S/
```

My desired input string is alphanumeric and / and - . I am trying to restrict a field having those values only

Strings that should pass

```
keuUiE/oieu-
O/KJju-Iu/kk
```

Strings that shouldnt pass

```
AHSos02@iek\
PwmwnWW(JJW
```

Comment: Well, *what* did not work? What were the input strings and the desired results? As it stands, you require an `S` in every string, is that what you're after?

Comment: Why your regex ends with literal `S`? Is it intended or source of your `didnt work`?

Comment: I am trying to use this regular expression to restrict a field property to that value

Comment: It ends with S because I just was trying and error

Comment: Please provide sample strings that should pass and that should not. Not it's passes any string that starts with single letter, number, slash, minus sign or # and has second char `S`

Comment: I have updated my OP with strings that should pass and not pass

Comment: Thanks Sean but I cannot write additional Java. I have a field that accepts a regex .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use a '-' in a character class, it has to be at the very end (or start, I guess?). Otherwise the parser might confuse it with a range operator (as in 'a-z').

If you change your regex from

- `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\/\-#]*/` to
- `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\/#-]*/`

it should work

Comment: Its giving invalid format even when i put just alphabets in it. When i removed the / in the prefix and suffix, it works, but i am still testing it with different strings